# how to fix error #2002 mysql with wamp

Tags: mysql

this is a part file mysql.log

```
2014-11-24 16:16:08 b68  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
2014-11-24 16:16:08 2816 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-11-24 16:16:08 2816 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2014-11-24 16:16:08 2816 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-11-24 16:16:08 2816 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to install the InnoDB Storage for MySQL, which version of MySQL do you currently have installed? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-installation.html